# Difficulty creating a data pipeline with Fabric Datafactory using REST

Tags: azure, rest, azure-data-factory, fabric

I am creating a data pipeline in Fabric Data Factory using date as a parameter. However, the system presents the following error:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gbUuX.png)

And I wanted to pass a date in variable format that always collects the current day and sets it in the variable {vi}, and the day following {vi} in {vf}.

However, I can't get the system to work even by passing the dates in a fixed way as shown in the example below:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3WVwt.png)

However, I get this error:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LoV3b.png)

Does anyone have any ideas on how I should proceed in this case?

Comment: Are you using pagination or does your api just need the date as a parameter? Can you show us what a valid API call looks like ? And also the full settings in your linked service and activity